# Haskell - Checking if all list elements are unique

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, comparison

I need to compare if all elements of a given list are unique.
(For the record I am doing so for academic purposes.)

Here is what I have thus far:

```
allDifferent :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
allDifferent list = case list of
    []      -> True
    (x:xs)  -> if x `elem` xs then False else allDifferent xs
```

Which works wonderfully!

Now, when I try to do it like this...

```
allDifferent2 :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
allDifferent2 list
    | null list                                                     = True        
    | (head list) `elem` (tail list) || allDifferent2 (tail list)  = False
    | otherwise
```

It just doesn't work as intended.
I get the following output from GHCi:

```
*Main> allDifferent2 [1..4]
False
*Main> allDifferent2 [1..5]
True
*Main> allDifferent2 [1..6]
False
*Main> allDifferent2 [1..7]
True
```

i.e. For every list with an even amount of elements it outputs False and for an odd amount of elements, True.

What am I missing?
Would anyone care to shine some light?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `null list = True` to match your original implementation?

Comment: Yes sorry .. typo.. just fixed that, the bug however, persists.

Comment: So you have ```head list `elem` tail list || allDifferent2 (tail list) = False```, which is basically saying "if the first element is somewhere in the list, or if all the rest of the list is full of uniques then return False".  Are you sure that's the behavior you want?  You might be able to make it simpler with ```head list `elem` tail list = allDifferent2 (tail list)```, I think that'll work better for you.

Comment: If your recursive call to `allDifferent2` returns True then the guard passes and you then return False which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An alternative exploiting `notElem`:

```
allDifferent :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
allDifferent list = case list of
    []      -> True
    (x:xs)  -> x `notElem` xs && allDifferent xs
```

Minor variant, using pattern matching directly in the equations:

```
allDifferent :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
allDifferent []     = True
allDifferent (x:xs) = x `notElem` xs && allDifferent xs
```

I tend to stay away from partial functions like `head,tail`, so the variants based on guards look worse to me.

Comment: Interesting, what harm is there in using partial functions?

Comment: The final code utilizing guards looks like this: `allDifferent3::(Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
allDifferent3 list
    | list == []                        = True
    | (head list) `notElem` (tail list) = allDifferent3 $ tail list
    | allDifferent3(tail list)          = False`

Comment: @LuisDosReis If you ever ask for `head []` or `tail []`, the whole program aborts (crashes). This does not happen with (exhaustive) pattern matching. (And `-Wall` helps in detecting non exhaustiveness).

Comment: @LuisDosReis In a guard solution, remember you have to add an `| otherwise = blah ` case

Comment: Hm, even when my matches already cover all of the possibilities?.

Comment: Edit: Just noticed my code does not cover all possibilities.. Just fed some strings into it and some larger arrays and it throws a non-exhaustive patterns exception.. And as you said adding `| otherwise =  False` in the end does the trick. Thanks! (Must admit though the `case .. of` solution is far more elegant and succinct.)

Comment: @LuisDosReis If your code ends with a list of guards, the last must be equivalent to `otherwise`, since it has to catch all the remaining cases. You may use a more complex check, but there's no real reason to do so.

Comment: @LuisDosReis It's much easier to work with total functions. In fact you can derive theorems from the type of a total function and be sure that it has some property simply looking at the type. If the function is partial this kind of things gets harder, because the function could blow up at any time and you generally cannot easily derive properties as easily. This makes both reasoning and proving correctness much more difficult.

Answer (score 5):

I would do this differently. Recursion + `elem` is *O(n²)*. Alternatively you can first sort the list, and then compare elements pairwise. This way the sorting is *O(n⋅log n)*, and the traversal *O(n)*. So overall *O(n⋅log n)*:

```
import Data.List

allDifferent :: (Ord a, Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
allDifferent = comparePairwise.sort

comparePairwise :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
comparePairwise [] = True
comparePairwise [_] = True
comparePairwise (x:y:xs) 
    | x == y = False
    | otherwise = comparePairwise (y : xs)
```

Comment: I'd suggest `comparePairwise (x:xs@(y:_)) = x /= y && comparePairwise xs ; comparePairwise _ = True`

Comment: @chi Agree. It's more elegant.

Comment: The usual approach is `comparePairwise xs = and $ zipWith (/=) xs (drop 1 xs)`.

Comment: @dfeuer Succinct. The logic isn't quite clear to a novice like me though. Not a problem however after some research.  Would you be able to judge how this compares performance wise to the above solution?

Comment: @Luis Dos Reis The asymptotic time is still linear, so no performance change from algorithmic point of view.

Comment: @LuisDosReis, the performance should be okay, but it may allocate more memory than the hand-written version, or maybe less. The best way would be to measure performance.

Comment: However, this is less generic because of the `Ord` constraint.

Comment: @Cactus Well noticed. I wonder if there a way to achieve the same time complexity without ordering relation.

Comment: You don't need to specify that a must have an Eq instance since Ord already include Eq

Answer (score 3):

You can rely on library functions: `allDifferent xs = nub xs == xs`.

Or, written in point-free notation: `allDifferent = uncurry (==) . (nub &&& id)`.

Using [Data.Discrimination.nub](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/discrimination-0.1/docs/Data-Discrimination.html#v:nub), this happens in *O(n)* time.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest reasonable idiomatic approach I can think of is

```
allDifferent :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
allDifferent = pairwiseDifferent . sort

pairwiseDifferent :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
pairwiseDifferent xs = and $ zipWith (/=) xs (drop 1 xs)
```

For fun with folds,

```
import Data.Maybe

pairwiseDifferent xs = foldr go (const True) xs Nothing
  where
    go x k Nothing = k (Just x)
    go x k (Just prev) = x /= prev && k (Just x)
```

Another option is to use a `Set` (some of the strictness annotations may not actually be necessary):

```
import qualified Data.Set as S

allDifferent xs = foldr go (\s -> s `seq` True) xs S.empty
  where
    go x k s
       | S.member x s = False
       | otherwise = k $! S.insert x s
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
allDifferent2::(Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
allDifferent2 list
    | list == []                        = True
    | (head list) `elem` (tail list)    = False
    | otherwise = allDifferent2(tail list)
```

If the list is [] you should return True (As @bheklilr said :) )

If the list isn't null, you can verify if the first element is in the tail of the list. If it is, return False. Okay.

But when you say "if it is in the tail of the list **OR** allDifferent2 (tail list)" you are killing your function. "If all the elements are different in this list, return **FALSE**", and that isn't what you want.

**EDIT:** Yeah, it will @Luis. I fixed that by putting that "otherwise" there. When I put the guard before the allDifferent2(tail list) it checked if this function returned True. Thus it would work for [1, 1, 2] (my test-case) but not for [1, 2, 2] (similar to your case).

Comment: I copied as you typed it. GHCi throws a Non-exhaustive patterns exception however when I input a list with elements which aren't unique..    `*Main> allDifferent3 [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]`
                 `*** Exception: allDiff.hs:(18,1)-(21,47): Non-exhaustive patterns in function allDifferent3`

Comment: Indeed. I edited my answer and now it should be ok. I tested the repetition case with [1, 1, 2] (starting with the repeated number) but not with [1, 2, 2]. But now it is right. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sort the list, [`group`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group) runs of equal elements together, and check if [`all`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all) groups have exactly one element.

```
import Data.List (group, sort)

pairwiseDistinct :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
pairwiseDistinct xs = all (\ys -> null (tail ys)) (group (sort xs))
```

Point-free version:

```
pairwiseDistinct = all (null . tail) . group . sort
```

This assumes that for any two elements `x` and `y`, `x == y` if and only if `compare x y == EQ`.

`tail` is fine here because none of the groups will ever be empty, but you can substitute `drop 1` if you're averse to partial functions.

Comment: Works but only when the elements are of type `Ord`.

Answer (score 0):

```
allDifferent []    = True
allDifferent (h:t) = 
                     let (e,(l,r)) = segment h t 
                     in e && allDifferent l && allDifferent r

segment p []     = (True,([],[])))
segment p (h:s) 
   | p > h       = let (e,(l,r)) = segment p s in (e,(l,h:r))
   | p < h       = let (e,(l,r)) = segment p s in (e,(h:l,r))
   | otherwise   = (False,([],[])))
```

As you can see the structure of this solution is very similar to quickSort.
It shares as an intermediate data structure a binary tree and for that reason, the time complexity is extremely similar.